# Angular $cookies "Circular dependency found"

Tags: angularjs, cookies, circular-dependency, angular-cookies

got this error "Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $cookies <- $cookies <- AuthService"

with following code

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('core.auth').
  factory('AuthService', [ '$http', '$rootScope', 'ConfigService', '$cookies',
    function AuthService($http, $rootScope, ConfigService, $cookies) {
      const service = {};

      service.Login = Login;
      service.SetCredentials = SetCredentials;
      service.ClearCredentials = ClearCredentials;

      return service;

      function Login(username, password, callback) {
        $http.post(ConfigService.LOGIN_API, { username: username, password: password })
           .success(function (response) {
               callback(response);
           });
      }

      function SetCredentials(username) {
        $rootScope.globals = {
          currentUser: {
            username: username
          }
        };

        $cookies.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
      }

      function ClearCredentials() {
        $rootScope.globals = {};
        $cookies.remove('globals');
      }
    }
]);
```

and i'm use this service in login component

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('login').
  component('login', {
    templateUrl: 'dist/components/login/login.template.html',
    controller: ['$location', 'AuthService', '$log',
      function LoginController($location, AuthService, $log) {

      (function initController() {
          // reset login status
          AuthService.ClearCredentials();
        }());

        this.login = () => {
          AuthService.Login(this.username, this.password, (response) => {
            if (response.success) {
              $log.log(response);
              $log.log('Login successful', true);
              AuthService.SetCredentials(this.username);
              $location.path('#!/products');
            } else {
              $log.log(response)
            }
          })
        }

      }
    ],

    controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

can't understand whats wrong with my code... If remove $cookies from here, it's working perfectly. Maybe solution is write own cookies service? :)

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your problem without seeing your other services. If you take time and isolate your problem in a Plnkr, someone on the site will probably help figure out your problem.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong tool for the purposes. I'm solved problem just replaced ngCookies -> ngStorage. Working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

A circular dependency is always the sign of **mixing of concerns**, which is a really bad thing.One of the authors of AngularJS, explains a nice solution [on his awesome blog](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/). In short, you probably have a third service hidden somewhere, which is the only part of your code really needed by the two others.